# 3 ticks not shown in Webmaster Tools dashboard

Tags: google-search-console

I am new to Webmaster Tools and just finished listing two of my sites. One of my sites I listed almost a week ago.

For one of the sites I have listed, I get the following on the dashboard:

[image: 3 ticks]

As far as I know Google shows those 3 ticks after a while, once you submit your site in Webmaster Tools.

However, for the site I have listed almost a week ago, I get the following shown on the dashboard:

[image: No ticks]

Why I am not getting the ticks, for the site I have almost listed a week ago? What does no ticks mean?

Answer (score 1):

You have nothing to worry about. Give it time and it will show up. A week to you is like a second to Google. In GWT things move slow and are not always accurate.